# Does there exist a poset with exactly 5 maximal chains of size 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, respectively and 2 maximal elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I came across this question today

> Does there exist a poset with exactly 5 maximal chains of size 2, 3,
> 4, 5, 6, respectively and 2 maximal elements?

I dont't know how to begin with this question? Can someone please provide some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formalize the following picture for an answer

[image]